# Normal curve 1.5 standard deviations

Tags: normal-distribution

For a normal curve, how much of the area lies within 1.5 standard deviations of the mean? I already know about the 68–95–99.7 rule, and see that it should be between 68% and 95%. I also know that it should be closer to 95%, so I estimate it to be around 80%. Can someone give me a hint on how to find the answer?

Comment: Look it up in a table or use a programming solution.  For example [this table](https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/9404) gives $P(X \le 1.5) \approx 0.9332$ though you want $P(-1.5 \le X \le 1.5)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. It's about 87%. And see: [probit](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit).

Comment: Combining henry's comment and rulnick's answer, I wanted to figure out how to get this answer using R, to compute $P(-1.5 < X < 1.5)$:

`> pnorm(1.5) - pnorm(-1.5) => [1] 0.8663856`

`> 1 - 2 * pnorm(-1.5) => [1] 0.8663856`

[This page](https://socratic.org/questions/what-percentage-of-the-population-values-fall-under-1-5-standard-deviations-in-a) has an interesting simplification, $1 - 2 * P(X < -1.5)$, as well.

Comment: Could you show your work or explain further, please?

Comment: For a random variable with density $f$, mean $\mu$, standard deviation $\sigma$, the area under $f$ within $k$ standard deviations of the mean is $\int_{\mu-k\sigma}^{\mu+k\sigma} f(u)\,du$, or $F(\mu+k\sigma)-F(\mu-k\sigma)$, where $F$ is its distribution. For a normal r.v., $F(u)=\Phi((u-\mu)/\sigma)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution, so the area of interest is $\Phi(k)-\Phi(-k)$, or $1-2\Phi(-k)$ since, due to $f$'s symmetry, $\Phi(k)=1-\Phi(-k)$. Here, $k=1.5$.